# RF WiFi Radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

I would like to extrapolate my current router wifi radiation from my phone.
If I know that my router is transmitting at 300mW and my phone displays the strength in -dbm (from 0 to -100 scale) if I have -50dbm strength does it mean that the current radiation is 150mW?
If not how can I extrapolate the radiation from -dbm scale?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking:  If the phone registers -50dBm, that means that the received strength at the phone is -50dBm.  Is your question about how to convert this to milliwatts?

Comment: Exatcly, I would like to convert it in mW/cm2 but I am no sure if the transmission power counts...
PS. I know that -60dbm is 10^(-60/10) mW
Thank you

Comment: But I think you've answered your own question if you substitute 50 for 60.  You don't need to know the transmission power - just use the mobile reading directly.

Comment: What do you mean extrapolate? Extrapolate for with respect to what? You already know how to convert from dmb to mW.

Comment: Is this that simple? Doesn't the transmission power count? I want to calculate the mW/cm2 as I have only DBm
Thank you all very much for your effort

Comment: If, with 300mW transmit power, your mobile shows -50dBm, then if, for example, you turn your power down on the router to 30mW, your mobile would then show -60dBm.  They're just (logarithmically) proportional.  All that matters for your purposes is the received power at the mobile.  If you want to know the flux density (mW/cm^2) at the location of the mobile, you need to know the mobile antenna's [effective aperture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture), to work out how much of the radiated power the mobile is collecting and displaying.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBW , -50 =10log10(X), power = 10^-5 *300 = 3 microwatt. -3db point for half power.

Comment: and how the Antenna aperture relates to this formula?
Is there any average value that I could use for mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to estimate the flux density (power per unit area) at a location based on a reading of the received power at a mobile device situated there.  The signal transmitted from the router will result in an energy density of radiated power, decreasing with distance.  The mobile device has a receive antenna which collects some of this RF power in its vicinity.  This receive antenna is characterized by a parameter called its "effective area", or "effective aperture".  This has the dimensions of an area, and if its value is $A \ cm^2$, then at a location where the RF power had a flux density of $F \ mW/cm^2$, the power captured by the antenna would be $FA \ mW$

Now the effective aperture is related to a parameter called the *antenna gain* by $$ G(\theta, \phi) = \frac{4\pi A(\theta, \phi)}{\lambda^2} $$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength.  Both the antenna gain and the effective aperture are functions of direction (specified by the two parameters $\theta$, $\phi$).  Antennas have varying degrees of directionality (for example a parabolic reflector is highly directional). The formula shows that the direction in which the gain is maximum also maximises the effective aperture.

Now for a few numbers - say the frequency $f = 2.4GHz$ (depends which WiFi band you're using), we get a wavelength $\lambda = 12.5cm$  Antennas on mobile devices are actually quite lossy, so lets assume a gain of -3dB in the given direction (i.e. 0.5 in linear terms).  This gives us $A = 6.2cm^2$

Your reading of -50dBm corresponds to $10^{-5} mW$, so the flux density is $10^{-5}/6.2 = 1.6^{-6}mW/cm^2$